# Vectorized code for a function to generate vector values

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Suppose we have a defined function as following, and we would like to `iterate over n from 1 to L`, I've suffered a lot for a vectorization code, since this code is rather slow due to for loop needed outside to call this function.

Details: `L, K` are large integers e.g. 1000 and `H_n` is float value.

```
def multifrac_Brownian_motion(n, L, K, list_hurst, ind_hurst):

    t_ks = np.asarray(sorted(-np.array(range(1, K + 1))*(1./L)))

    t_ns = np.linspace(0, 1, num=L+1)
    t_n = t_ns[n]

    chi_k = np.random.randn(K)
    chi_lminus1 = np.random.randn(L)

    H_n = get_hurst_value(t_n, list_hurst, ind_hurst)

    part1 = 1./(np.random.gamma(0.5 + H_n))

    sums1 = np.dot((t_n - t_ks)**(H_n - 0.5) - ((-t_ks)**(H_n - 0.5)), chi_k)
    sums2 = np.dot((t_n - t_ns[:n])**(H_n - 0.5), chi_lminus1[:n])

    return part1*(1./np.sqrt(L))*(sums1 + sums2)

for n in range(1, L + 1):
        onelist.append(multifrac_Brownian_motion(n, L, K, list_hurst, ind_hurst=ind_hurst))
```

---

Update:

```
def list_hurst_funcs(M, seg_size=10):
    """Generate a list of Hurst function components

    Args:
        M: Int, number of hurst functions
        seg_size: Int, number of segmentations of interval [0, 1]
    Returns:
        list_hurst: List, list of hurst function components
    """

    list_hurst = []

    for i in range(M):
        seg_points = sorted(np.random.uniform(size=seg_size))
        funclist = np.random.uniform(size=seg_size + 1)
        list_hurst.append((seg_points, funclist))

    return list_hurst


def get_hurst_value(x, list_hurst, ind):
    if np.isscalar(x):
        x = np.array(float(x), ndmin=1)

    seg_points, funclist = list_hurst[ind]

    condlist = [x < seg_points[0]] +\
                [(x >= seg_points[s] and x < seg_points[s + 1]) 
                                          for s in range(len(seg_points) - 1)] +\
                [x >= seg_points[-1]]

    return np.piecewise(x, condlist=condlist, funclist=funclist)
```

Comment: Could you share the implementation of `get_hurst_value`?

Comment: @Divakar The code is updated.

Comment: You have different levels of vectorization required/possible here. I would suggest vectorize it in steps. So, start with vectorizing `get_hurst_value`. I would advise posting a new question with sample inputs to it and the output from it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle a problem like this is to (try) understand the big picture, and come with a different approach that treats everything as 2d or larger (LxK arrays).  Another is to examine the `multifrac_Brownian_motion`, trying to speed it up, and where possible eliminate steps that depend on scalars or 1d arrays.  In other words, work from the inside out.  If we get enough of a speed improvement it may not matter that we have to call it in a loop.  Even better the improvement suggests ways of operating in high dimensions.

As a start from inside out, I'd suggest replacing the `t_ks` calc with:

```
t_ks = -np.arange(K,0,-1)/L    # 1./L if required by Py2 integer division
```

Since `list_hurst`, `ind_hurst` are the same for all `n`, I suspect you can move some time consuming parts of `get_hurst_value` outside the loop.

But I'd put most effort into improving that `condlist` construction.  That's list comprehension buried deep inside your outer loop.

`piecewise` also loops over those `seg_points`.